# What does "Lifetime scopes are respected" means?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm reading the [Implicit Relationship Types](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) Section in Autofac official documentation, but i don't really understand this line.

> Lifetime scopes are respected using this relationship type.

Who can help me explain that what on earth does 'respected' means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'respected' means Autofac will not override your registrations when you use Dynamic Instantiation.

This is elaborated in the next 2 lines:

> If you register an object as `InstancePerDependency()` and call the `Func<B>` multiple times, you’ll get a new instance each time. However, if you register an object as `SingleInstance()` and call the `Func<B>` to resolve the object more than once, you will get the same object instance every time.

---

Quoted from asker's comment:

> I understand the detailed explanations in the next 2 lines and i have wrote demos for that, but what's the connection to lifetime scope? Can I understand that lifetime scope is important, and will influence the instantiation?

The connection to lifetime scope:

*When you dependency-inject an object, do I give you a new object or **the** singleton?*

Why lifetime scope is important and will influence instantiation:

*Does the object have instance attributes that should not be accessed elsewhere? If I give you a new object, should it be a singleton that exists for the rest of the application's lifetime?*

Comment: I understand the detailed explanations in the next 2 lines and i have wrote demos for that,  but what's the connection to lifetime scope? Can I understand that lifetime scope is important, and will influence the instantiation?

Comment: The connection: *When you dependency-inject an object, do I give you a new object or **the** singleton?* Why lifetime scope is important: *Does the object have instance attributes that should not be accessed elsewhere? If I give you a new object, should it be a singleton that exists for the rest of the application's lifetime?*

Comment: You're welcome. I'll edit my answer to include my comment :)